# PySpark - Emr- NullpointerException while trying to insert into Glue(s3) table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I am trying to insert into the Glue Catalog table pointing to s3 location and reading from Redshift.

I am getting the below error, I am able to write directly to s3 without any issues. This issue started while trying to insert that is defined as parquet.

Spark 2.4 - EMR. This issue within just couple mins after data unloading from redshift and process starts.

```
19/12/08 20:44:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 410.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 944)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_0_21$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue and able to fix it. It is issue with the nullability of the columns. My source is REDSHIFT and there is an open issue with it as well. Here is link
https://kb.databricks.com/data-sources/redshift-npe.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the column as nullable true.

[SPARK-17195](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17195)